# Resolving dependencies with an XUnit2 project, similar to how it is done with an MVC6 Core 1.0 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, xunit, asp.net-core-1.0

I am attempting to create Unit tests that involve calling my Business Layer which in turn calls my Repository Layer.

**First, please see how I am doing this with my ASP.NET MVC6 WebApp which is working perfectly:**

```
//Startup.cs of MVC Web App
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddSingleton(_=> Configuration);

    services.AddTransient<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
    services.AddTransient<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();
}

public class CustomersController : Controller
{
    private ICustomerService _service;
    public CustomersController(ICustomerService service)
    {
        _service= service;
    }
}

public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{
    private ICustomerRepository _repository;
    public PriceProtectionManager(ICustomerRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}

public class CustomerRepository : BaseRepository, ICustomerRepository
{
    public CustomerRepository(IConfigurationRoot config) 
    : base(config)
    {
    }
}

public class BaseRepository
{
    private IConfigurationRoot _config;

    public BaseRepository(IConfigurationRoot config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
}
```

With the above in mind, please see where I am getting stuck resolving dependencies in an [XUnit project using a Class Fixture](https://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context.html#class-fixture) that has nothing to do with my MVC6 app.

**Here is what my Fixture class looks like:**

```
public class DatabaseFixture : IDisposable
{
    public ICustomerService CustomerService;
    public DatabaseFixture()
    {
        // HOW CAN I RESOLVE DEPENDENCIES HERE USING THE NEW ASP.NET DI
        CustomerService = service;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}

public class MyTests : IClassFixture<DatabaseFixture>
{
    DatabaseFixture fixture;
    public MyTests(DatabaseFixture fixture)
    {
        this.fixture = fixture;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void MyFirstTest()
    {
        fixture.CustomerRepository.GetAllCustomers();
    }
}
```

When I run at test I am getting an error that CustomerService is not resolved. I know why this is happening, I just don't know how to go about resolving these dependencies for my tests using the built in ASP.NET DI just like the MVC6 app does it.

I believe this [github post](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/687) is exactly what I am trying to do. Does anyone have a solution for this?

I believe what I want to know is how I can wire up dependencies in an XUnit Fixture using the new ASP.NET Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why I was looking into how to use Dependency Injection this entire time when I simply just needed to add an appsettings.json file to my Test Project that contains a db connection string and then do this in my TestFixture:

```
public class TestFixture : IDisposable
{
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
    public TestFixture()
    {
        // Set up configuration sources.
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

**Then in my Test class access the fixture like this:**

```
public class MyTests: IClassFixture<TestFixture>
{
    TestFixture fixture;
    public MyTests(TestFixture fixture)
    {
        this.fixture = fixture;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void MyFirstTest()
    {
        ICustomerRepository customerRepository = new CustomerRepository(fixture.Configuration);
        CustomerService customerService = new CustomerService(customerRepository);        
}
```

As you can see I am able to call fixture.Configuration to satisfy the needs of instantiating a new Customer Repository.

This solution gives me full flexibility to swap out my repository layer per unit test and specify which services each unit test needs. If you want to specify your Services at the TestFixture level and make them public properties so it is only created one time for all tests and you can simply call fixture.CustomerService within your tests.